# .NET multiple gmail accounts with 2 webbrowser controls

Tags: c#, .net, browser, gmail

I have a tab control with 2 tabs with a webbrowser control on each of them.
i want to display 2 diffrent gmail accounts on them but the minute i log through webbrowser1 webbrowser 2 logs on as well.

is there a way to preform what i want?

Comment: Is this behaviour even possible with a normal browser? Having two different gmail accounts in two separate tabs logged in concurrently?

Comment: The design of Gmail itself largely prevents this from working.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible I think to do it in the way you are trying....as Webrowser component is the internet explorer of your syatem

What you can do is use [Gecko](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) in the second tab

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 offers a "New Session" function in the UI.  I would imagine that this feature is possible to implement in your own UI as well.  See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx) on how it works in the UI.  Search the Web Browser Control documentation for a way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will give you access to an InPrivate IE

```
Friend Function Open(Optional ByVal Url As String = "about:blank", Optional ByVal WindowState As ProcessWindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden) As WebBrowser
On Error Resume Next

Dim Start As New ProcessStartInfo
Dim Windows = New ShellWindowsClass
Dim Count = Windows.Count
Start.FileName = "iexplore.exe"
Start.Arguments = "-private -nomerge " & Url
If WindowState = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden Then
  Start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Else
  Start.WindowStyle = WindowState
End If
Process.Start(Start)

Wait.Reset()
Do
  If Windows.Count > Count Then Exit Do
Loop While Wait.Waiting

Browser = Windows(Count)
Browser.Visible = (WindowState <> ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden)
Return Browser
End Function
```